# Dividir consulta MySql en un Array Multidimencional

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, array

Actualmente, estoy trabajando con Laravel en una consulta en la cual los resultados recibidos son así:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1339 ▼
#items: array:9 [▼
0 => {#1347 ▼
  +"id": "1"
  +"name": "Activity 1"
}
1 => {#1340 ▼
  +"id": "2"
  +"name": "Activity 2"
}
2 => {#1346 ▼
  +"id": "3"
  +"name": "Activity 3"
}
3 => {#1343 ▼
  +"id": "4"
  +"name": "Activity 4"
}
4 => {#1344 ▼
  +"id": "5"
  +"name": "Activity 5"
}
5 => {#1348 ▼
  +"id": "6"
  +"name": "Activity 6"
}
6 => {#1341 ▶}
7 => {#1349 ▼
  +"id": "7"
  +"name": "Activity 7"
}
8 => {#1350 ▼
  +"id": "8"
  +"name": "Activity 8"
}
]
}
```

Y quiero separar los resultados en un array multidimencional, pero solo los nombre de las actividades que en cada array solo vaya dos actividades y tener algo parecido:

```
activities = [
    ["Activity 1", "Activity 2"],
    ["Activity 3", "Activity 4"],
    ["Activity 5", "Activity 6"],
    ["Activity 7", "Activity 8"]
]
```

He intentado con *array_pluck* pero no me funciono me fuciono todo el resultado :(

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
function groupArray($array){
    // almacenara los grupos resultado
    $group = array();
    // for comun pero sumamos a $i 2 para que no aumento de 1 en 1 
    for($i = 1; $i <= count($array); $i= ( $i + 2 ) ){
        
        // simpre existira una posicion menor
        $tmp = array($array[$i-1]);
        
        // validamos que la posicion exista
        if( isset( $array[$i] )){
            $tmp [] =$array[$i] ;
        }
        // hacemos un push al arreglo principal
        $group [] = $tmp ;
    }
    
    // retornamos los resultados
    return $group;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la solución con un poco de investigación y ayuda de un amigo, solo había que crear un variable array pincipal y otro hijo

```
$p = array();
$h = array();

// $array es mi resultado de la bd
// recorro el resultado

foreach($array as $value){
    $h[] = $value->name  // agrego el nombre al array hijo
    if (count($h) == 2) { // cuento si en el array hay dos valores
       $p[] = $h; // si es asi lo agrego al array padre
       $h = array(); // y vuelvo al array hijo de nuevo vacio
   }
}

// Por ultimo solo valido que no agregue array vacios al padre

if (!empty($h)) {
   $p[] = $h;
}

return $p;
```

y como resultado obtuve:

```
array:5 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
        0 => "Activity 1"
        1 => "Activity 2"
    ]
    1 => array:2 [▼
        0 => "Activity 3"
        1 => "Activity 4"
    ]
    2 => array:2 [▼
         0 => "Activity 5"
         1 => "Activity 6"
    ]
    3 => array:2 [▼
         0 => "Activity 7"
         1 => "Activity 8"
    ]
    4 => array:1 [▼
         0 => "Activity 9"
    ]
]
```